# How to test sample Android Wear watchface app?

Tags: android, android-studio, wear-os

After opening Android Wear WatchFace Sample app from Google, how do you test/install it on the emulator? (Note: the emulator is already using the 5.0 build)

When run, you got Default Activity not found error.

[image: Error Screenshot]

If choose "Do not launch Activity", you will get the following warning message, after proceeding it will failed since it cannot uninstall the default app.

[image: Warning Screenshot]

Comment: To answer my own question: I still did not get this work out, but on another machine it works perfectly so I am now developing on another machine.

Comment: Which one "App" or "Wearable" to execute Run? I cannot find it on both phone and watch after run...

Answer (score 10):

Change the Activity section option to `Do not launch activity` - this will cause the run button to just install your watch face. You can then proceed to manually select the watch face on the emulator (if needed - if you've already selected it the changes will appear immediately).

Comment: And what happens when you hit OK?

Comment: DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.example.android.wearable.watchface"
pkg: /data/local/tmp/com.example.android.wearable.watchface
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_DEXOPT]


DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm uninstall com.example.android.wearable.watchface
DELETE_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR